how to TextChangedEventArgs in Maui MVVM
I want to get TextChangedEventArgs in MVVM and I don't know how. Thanks for your help
<Entry Text="{Binding Text}">
    <Entry.Behaviors>
        <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged"
                          Command="{Binding TextChangedCommand}"/>
    </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.maui.controls.textchangedeventargs?view=net-maui-8.0

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior#accessing-the-eventargs-from-the-event

@Jason Thanks! Can you answer as the answer? Like this, I can approve it :)

By using the EventToCommandBehavior implementation the EventArgs will be passed into the Command property if both the CommandParameter and Converter properties are not set. To refer to the generic type in XAML we need to make use of the x:TypeArguments directive.
So basically this would work for you
<Entry.Behaviors>
    <behaviors:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="TextChanged"
                      x:TypeArguments="TextChangedEventArgs"
                      Command="{Binding TextChangedCommand}"/>
</Entry.Behaviors>

Let me know if you have any questions
